# How To Capture Mouse Movement Over Caption Bar In C++ Win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I have my own custom painted caption bar for a window. I have also painted a bitmap on this bar which I want to know when someone hovers over it with the mouse cursor. I have handled the `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE` message but this seems to only be triggered over the borders and not my caption area itself.

How can I detect when the mouse is over a certain area of the caption bar?

This is with Visual C++ 2010.

Update:

I have worked out the problem to an extent. I (deliberately) do not have the `WS_CAPTION` style set on the window and instead I handle the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` and manually adjust the size of the non-client area - shifting it down by 20 pixels in this case. This means that the area that I am "forcing" as a non-client area does not get `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE` messages but neither does it get `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages either. One way round it is to force the `WM_CAPTION` style, get rid of my custom code on `WM_NCCALCSIZE` but this isn't ideal. Is there a way round it?

Update2:

It is the same problem with `WM_NCHITTEST` messages. The area does not get these triggered unless I have `WS_CAPTION` style set which I don't want. Also it is somehow affecting the client area in that it no longer gets `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` messages.

Comment: Are you sure no window in your hierarchy catches those WM_NCMOUSEMOVE messages? Have you tried Spy++ (from Visual Studio Tools) on your window?

Comment: Yes I am using my own Window Proc for all messages to the window and it's not getting any unless I am hovering over the borders.

Comment: You should process the WM_NCHITTEST message and make it return HTCAPTION when appropriate

Comment: I've added some more info the original post.

Comment: Processing WM_NCHITTEST makes no difference. The area isn't getting those messages either. It also stops LBUTTONDOWN handling working in the client area for some reason.

Comment: Are you handling WM_NCCREATE in your window procedure, without passing it to `DefWindowProc`?

Comment: Post the precise list of Window Styles you use in CreateWindow

Comment: No I am not handling WM_NCCREATE. Styles are ->Attr.Style |= WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS;

Comment: Oring with an unknown value is not what I call "precise" :-) So your Window is not a main Window child of the Desktop?

Comment: I think it's time to stop the game of 20 questions in the comments and insist on seeing an SSCCE.

Comment: [Child Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#child): *A child window has a client area but no other features, unless they are explicitly requested.*

Comment: @Tim Please tell us: is your window a child window of another window of yours, or do you intent to make it a top-level window?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite positive what you mean, but I think you are saying you want to check for a certain section of the caption bar being moused over. if so, then maybe try tracking window size and position, and then check to see if, relative to your window position and size, that section of the bar would be moused over (in pixels). This is the only way I can think of that doesn't use OS specific functions, which I try my best to avoid.